# Using a CALayer in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uikit, calayer, core-graphics

On each cell of my table view I want to have a bar that the user can slide out from the right.  On the bar I plan to have icons.  So, to do this I subclassed UITableViewCell.  On the cell I have implemented drawRect and in there I have already drawn a gradient and background color on the cell.  From there, I can create a CALayer, give it a frame & background color, and add it as a sub layer to the Views subLayers array.  I can do all that and it will display my layer on each UITableViewCell.

I have added touch events to the cell so I can detect when the user touches the cell and for testing I have made it so when the user swipes, my CALayer gets wider.  But the issue is, when the UITableView scrolls and reuses a cell whose CALayer has been widened, it doesn't recreate the CALayer.  I have tried

```
[myLayer setNeedsDisplay]
```

and used the drawLayer:inContext method of its delegate and it doesn't get called.  I have also tried telling call setNeedsDisplay on the cell in my UITableViewController hoping that that will cause a redraw, but it doesn't work.

I'm not sure what I'm missing.  I am new to CoreGraphics & CoreAnimation.  I have read through the CoreAnimation Developers Guide, but I'm assuming I missing something.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a closed transform and open transform to the CALayer.  In the table view controller's scrollViewWillBeginDragging, I iterate over all the visible cells and call apply my closed transform to reset the menu.